# Where to add FilterChain when using with Shell Script

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, thumbnails, mp4

I am trying to get a jpg out of an mp4 video's middle. I used this line and it works like charm for generating jpg thumbnail in one line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print $3/2}'` output.jpg
```

However, I want to apply scaling and cropping a filter chain (`filter:v`) with the above line, but where ever I put the filter, I couldn't make it work.

`-filter:v "scale=720:ih*720/iw, crop=720:720:280:1000"`.

Where should I put it?

The errors I receive:

> `At least one output file must be specified`
>
> `Invalid duration specification for ss: -filter:v`

Please note that this works:

`ffmpeg -i fkj.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -filter:v "scale=720:ih*720/iw, crop=720:720:280:1000" -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss 4  output.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it after `-vcodec mjpeg` and add this to the shell ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f null - 2>&1 | grep Duration....
```

Ideally, you should use `ffprobe input.mp4` instead of ffmpeg

Comment: _ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -filter:v "scale=720:ih*720/iw, crop=720:720:280:1000" -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print $3/2}'` output.jpg_ throws `At least one output file must be specified`

Comment: Test with a specified number like `-ss 4` instead of shell script

Comment: Yes, it works.. But why doesn't it work with the shell script?